# Can I render special characters using SVG in a browser

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I am building a graph using the SVG library [RaphealJS](http://raphaeljs.com/). I would like to label one of the axes as F° Can special characters be included in SVG text elements?

I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
paper.text(10, 10, 'F&deg;')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can simply add the character explicitly. There's no need to special encoding. The character is <strike>option+0</strike> option+shift+8 on my mac, and it displays correctly in SVG.

Comment: That will probably work fine, but you may want to replace it with a Unicode character reference, just to ensure there won't be any encoding issues: `paper.text(10, 10, 'F\u00B0');`

Comment: @BenBlank I disagree. Use your literal degree symbol (actually option-shift-8; option-0 is the "masculine ordinal number") and simply be sure to save your source file as UTF-8 and indicate that the encoding is UTF-8 (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`).

Comment: @Phrogz — It's possible I'm overly cynical when it comes to browsers obeying encodings, and using/specifying UTF-8 everywhere is indeed practically a sure thing.  Still, why do you suggest *not* using escapes?  As far as I'm aware, those *are* a sure thing.

Comment: @BenBlank I suggest not using them because they are harder to enter and read in the source. There are a lot of bad habits in web development that have been propagated because novices often copy one another's work blindly. If there are any user agents or programs that do not correctly handle properly-specified Unicode, we should be smoking them out by boldly embracing a better solution instead of cowering behind annoying workarounds that we perpetuate "just in case".

Comment: @Phrogz — Fair enough.  Of course, annoying is in the eye of the beholder; on Windows, I find escape codes to be much easier to work with than "alt codes".